# Android custom back button with text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I want in my Android app an action bar like the one I have in my iOS app:

[image].

Unfortunately I don't know how to make the back button with text only and how to move the title in the center. This would be for the entire application, not only one layout.

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: hey you can create one layout for that & include it in your activity, if you need it visit & download my sample demo you will get there https://github.com/mukeshlokare/SampleAndroidApp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a simple solution.

You have just to create a layout for a custom ActionBar `custom_action_bar_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:text="name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Back"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and then in your `ExampleActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_date);

    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar_layout, null);
    TextView title = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    title.setText("Title");
    TextView backButton = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.back_button);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

[and this is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTVg9.png)

Comment: Great solution!! +1 from me.

Comment: Oh!  on a null object reference

Answer (score 1):

You can create one `custom_toolbar.xml` layout & design what you want to achieve,

**See my paradigm**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_back"
                style="@style/TextStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawablePadding="0dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Back" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_name"
                style="@style/TextStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_value"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_back"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_value"
                style="@style/TextStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="test" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Now you can include this layout in your `example_activity.xml`

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**& See desired output**

[image]

Comment: ok thank you very much, but then how can I trigger the click of the button or set the title? @mukesh_lokare