# how to change the text of textview in custom actionbar using child fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

I have a child fragment inside the parent fragment.
I want to change the text of the `TextView` in custom ActionBar from child fragment here is my code and it gives me an error of null object reference
I have created a custom layout for action bar and inflate this layout with action bar.

Now I have four fragments in main activity. In first fragment there are four buttons. when I tap on the first button it opens another fragment. 
I want to change the text of the `TextView` from child fragment in custom ActionBar which is inflated with the main activity. the fragment name is `Qoutes` fragment and I want to change the text of `TextView` to `Quotes`.

How I can do this:

[image]

Comment: [Here's solution for changing back button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242280/android-custom-back-button-with-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Try like this:

```
 ((your_activity) getActivity()).setHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

You need to cast `getActivity()` with the name of your Activity.

Ex: `((MainActivity) getActivity()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);`

Same way you can change the text as well:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Your title");
```

Any issues, Please comment.